# How to bind MvxTableViewSource to dynamically created ViewModel with MvvmCross and Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have created table source and want to bind it not to current data context but to another ViewModel which is dynamically created by Controller.

```
//some button click

var context = new DynamicViewModel();
var source = new MyTableViewSource();
source.ItemsSource = context.DataItems; //I want this line to work with bindings
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the dynamic view model in your main view model and then just do the binding using that?  Set.Bind(source).For(ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.DynamicVM.Items)

Comment: that is plan for refactoring, as for now those dynamic viewmodels are created within the View code and this is probably my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the View side, Mvx bindings work for the `IMvxBindingContextOwner` rather that directly to the `ViewModel` - this allows them to update when the entire ViewModel is changed.

So, to do what you want to do, you'll need to provide an `IMvxBindingContextOwner` which holds your dynamic view model within its as the current DataContext within its BindingContext.

To do this, try creating a dummy owner like:

```
 public class MyOwner : IMvxBindingContextOwner 
 { 
     public MyOwner() { BindingContext = new MvxBindingContext(); {
     public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; private set; } 
 }
```

You should then be able to use that as a target for a new binding set - e.g.

```
 _owner = new MyOwner();
 _owner.BindingContext.DataContext = dynamicViewModel;
 var set = _owner.CreateBindingSet<MyOwner, DynamicViewModel>(); 
 // set.Bind statements
 set.Apply();
```

Not tested... but should work... If you hit problems, then also consider using the ready-made `MvxView` control - it is a `BindingContextOwner` and you can set its `DataContext`

Comment: awesome, this approach makes the binding really flexible